# How do I write to my JSON file more than once? when clicking onPressed?

Tags: flutter

Each time I restart my code, I get to run my writeToDatabase once, so it adds to list once. But any additional taps on my button does nothing.

When tapping my onPressed button, it sort of "redo" it's function. Or I'm not completely sure. I'm assuming it has something to do with async, but not fully grasping it.

Or maybe it's because I'm using context?
I've tried to set everything to final but it didn't work. Or maybe it's because of "tree shaking"? That it loads the file into memory and that's the file I keep modifying, and not, a new file after each run of my function, when tapping my button?

I got my onPressed:

```
      onPressed: () {
          writeToDatabase("wwwwwww", "fff?`!!", context);
        },
```

And I got my writeToDatabase function:

```
writeToDatabase(dynamic imagePath, dynamic textValue, context) async {
  Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String path = directory.path;
  File file = File('$path/database.json');
  // File file = await _localFile;
  String userJson = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(file.path);
  List userData = jsonDecode(userJson);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson = {
    'imagePath': imagePath,
    'textValue': textValue,
  };

  userData.add(toJson);
  return file.writeAsString(json.encode(userData));
}
```

Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: Some debugging steps: check what’s actually getting called- is your onPressed getting called? Your writeToDatabase? Print statements are a good way to find out. There’s not enough info here to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was right in front of me, I just didn't know where to look.

```
String userJson = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(file.path);
```

Has to be changed to:

```
String userJson = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(file.path, cache: false);
```

It turns out, it was constantly looking at a cashed version of the file.